# openxml - delete rows and move needed rows to new row

Tags: c#, vb.net, openxml

I would like to do some modifications to an existing excel sheet.I would like to remove the rows that I do not want to keep and reorder the rows that I do want to keep. I am using OpenXML Spreadsheet and in my code, I was able to successfully traverse the sheet and remove the rows and keep the ones I want according to a list of row indexes that I want to keep. However, I am having trouble reordering the row that I want to keep. Here is my code:

```
'open the glossary document
        Using document As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, True)



            Dim wbPart As WorkbookPart = document.WorkbookPart
            If wbPart Is Nothing Then
                Console.WriteLine("can't find workbook")
            End If

            ' Find the correct worksheet, given its name. 
            Dim sheet = _
              wbPart.Workbook.Descendants(Of Sheet)(). _
              Where(Function(s) s.Name = worksheetName).FirstOrDefault
            If sheet Is Nothing Then
                Console.WriteLine(worksheetName & " sheet does not exist")
            End If

            Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = CType(wbPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id), WorksheetPart)
            ' In the worksheet, retrieve a collection of rows where the 
            ' row index matches the row you're trying to delete. Although you 
            ' know there's only one such row, the Descendants method returns
            ' a collection.

            Dim rowindex As Integer
            Dim theSheet As Sheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants(Of Sheet)().Where(Function(s) s.Name = worksheetName).FirstOrDefault()
            Dim wsPart As WorksheetPart = CType(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id), WorksheetPart)
            Dim rows = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants(Of Row)()

            Dim bolDelete As Boolean


            For rowindex = intGlossaryStartRow To rows.Count

                bolDelete = True
                'PrintBR("Processing row: " & rowindex.ToString)

                For Each lst As Integer In glossaryRowList
                    If rowindex = lst Then
                        bolDelete = False
                    End If

                Next

                If bolDelete Then
                    'PrintBR("Deleting row: " & rowindex.ToString)
                    Dim deletingRow = _
                                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants(Of Row)(). _
                                Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowindex).FirstOrDefault()
                    If deletingRow Is Nothing Then
                        ' The specified row does not exist.
                        'PrintBR("ROW " & rowindex.ToString & " is nothing! [[[[[[[[[[[[ ABORT ]]]]]]]]]]]]]")
                        'Return
                    End If
                    Try
                        deletingRow.Remove()
                        'deletingRow.Hidden = True
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try


                Else
                    'this row collection is in the GlossaryRowList
                    Dim keepingRow = _
                            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants(Of Row)(). _
                            Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowindex).FirstOrDefault()
                    'get the index of the rowindex value in GlossaryRowList
                    Dim listIndex As Integer = glossaryRowList.IndexOf(rowindex)


                    'try to insert the keepingRow at row listIndex
                    Try

                        sheet.InsertAt(keepingRow, intGlossaryStartRow + listIndex)


                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try
                End If

            Next


            ' Save the worksheet part.
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()


        End Using
```

The **deleting.Remove()** method works, but the **sheet.InsertAt(keepingRow, intGlossaryStartRow + listIndex)** does not work. Am I calling the wrong method? Am I calling the right method on the wrong object? Please help.

Below are screenshots of the original excel sheet that I want to modify and the resulting sheet I get.

**Original**:
[original excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iynvy.png)

**Result**:
[result excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rXmY.png)

Comment: If openxml works the same way with Excel as it works with Word, you can't insert an existing node like that, you have to clone it.
When you do sheet.InsertAt(), do a CloneNode(true) on your keepingRow (at the end you will need to delete the original row).
(I can't assure it will work on Excel, I do more word Openxml ;) but the logic should be the same)

Comment: hey thanks! Should i do the CloneNode(true) before or after the insert?

Comment: You do it while inserting : sheet.InsertAt(keepingRow.CloneNode(true)
You have to insert a new node

Comment: Still not working... You mentioned that I need to delete the original row?

Comment: You need to delete the original row to not have it duplicated

Comment: Still not working... I tried keepingRow.Remove() after sheet.Insert(keepingRow.CloneNode(true)) and still same result.... :(